# Search value in multiple column according to below query using laravel query builder?

Tags: mysql, laravel

Please let me clear about the syntax.My question is that ,How to write the below query `Laravel 4.2` query builder?

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE 123 IN (col1, col2, col3, col4);
```

How to write query in Laravel 4.2? In that i have to search `string` in multiple column.

Comment: @Drew This question is somewhere different from you mentioned.

So please open that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
DB::table('table')->whereRaw('123 in (col1, col2, col3, col4));
```

OR

If you made model for the tabel

```
table::whereRaw('123 in (col1, col2, col3, col4));
```